# PHP different grid sizes in foreach loop

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I'm trying to get the following layout using PHP

[image]

My code:

```
<div class="grid">

<?php
foreach( $rows as $i => $row ) :
  if ( $i % 3 == 0 ) :
    $size = "large";
  else :
    $size = "small";
  endif;
?>

  <div class="item <?php echo $size; ?>"></div>

<?php endforeach; ?>

</div>
```

This makes the first item large on each row. How can I make the first item large on the first row, the last item large on the second row, first item large on third row, and so on in that pattern, like in the layout example?

Note: I must get the layout in PHP using the `$size` variable, not using CSS selectors because there is more to the code. I use CSS only to set the width of large or small items.

Comment: What values are your `$rows` and `$row` variables?

Comment: @MaxVoisard that does not really matter. It's just a loop for getting values which do not matter in the demo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that's what your are looking for:

```
<div class="grid">
    <?php
    foreach( $entries as $i => $entry ) :
        $size = "small";

        if ( $i % 6 == 0 || $i % 6 == 5 ) :
            $size = "large";
        endif;
    ?>

        <div class="item <?php echo $size; ?>"></div>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

You just need to change your modulo number to `6` because you're stuff repeats every 6 entries. And then you just need to check if it's on the first position or the last position eq. 0 or 5.